# Save a package specific plot to pdf R

Tags: r, plot, pdf-generation

I use the package `esd` (see reproductible code below) which is climatology package.

The package has several custom `map()` and `plot()` functions. 
I save my plots to Pdf's. `map()` function work well doing:

```
x<-my.field.object   
CairoPDF(file="/path/to/file.pdf")
map.field(x)
dev.off()
```

However `plot` doesn't work. Doing the same code as above, it will actually plot (with `x11()`) in Rstudio and nothing will be output to the pdf file.

I tried looking inside the function but can't see anything that make it behave like that.

Any idea?

P.S: for those who would like to try, the package has some field data in it, for example

Reproducible code:

```
#devtools::install_github("metno/esd")
library("Cairo") 
x<-t2m.NCEP(lon=c(-40,40),lat=c(30,70))
CairoPDF(file="/path/to/file.pdf")
plot.field(x)
dev.off()
```

EDIT: I'm aware of the dev.print solution. It works, but the problem is that i actually need to put several plot.field into one PDF file.

Comment: Instead of pointing people to another site where they have to figure out how to first install a package before answering your question, make it easy on people who are trying to help you by including commented-out installation code (`#devtools::install_github("metno/esd")`) in your reproducible example. Also, include `library(Cairo)`.

Comment: you might try wrapping `map.field(x)` in the print function: `print9map.field(x))`

Comment: After running `plot.field(x)` you could try `quartz.save(file="/path/to/file.pdf", type="pdf")`, but I don't think that will use the `Cairo` device.

Comment: Unfortunately none of this seems to work. wrapping the plot.field(x) into print doesn't write to cairo. The solution offered by eipi10 seems to work only for OS x platform (i'm under linux)